# How to select elements from another element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, select

Example Div:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="select1"></div>
    <div class="select2"></div>
    <div class="select3"></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to be able to select "div.container div.select2" with jQuery. The typical way that I would do it is like this:

```
$('.container')[0].getElementsByClassName('select2')[0]
```

But I want to change the JS query to a jQuery query. Something like this but that actually works:

```
$('.container')[0].$('.select2')[0]
```

Comment: [Ta-da-daaam!](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)... [Ta-da-da-da-daaam!](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('div.container div.select2')
```

or:

```
$('div.container div.select2')[0] // this selects the raw dom element
```

Comment: This worked, but now I came to another issue. What if there are two divs with the class 'container' and I want to select 'select2' ONLY from the first div?

Comment: @AaronWalker you can use `eq()`: `$('div.container:eq(0) div.select2')`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

```
$($('.container')[0], '.select2')[0]
```

or

```
$('.container', '.select2')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already cached `var myObj = $('div.container')`

```
myObj.find('.select2')[0]
```

One thing to note, you don't NEED `[0]` unless you're trying to do something to the actual DOM element. If you're trying to perform jQuery functions on your selection, omit the `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('div.container div.select2')` .

BTW, you can use `$('div.select2')` to query selcet2 directly.